# Will the following two queries give the same output consistently?

Tags: sql, oracle, exists, not-exists

We want to find the deptno of those departments having employees who can do some work done by employee in depertment 20.

```
SELECT deptno
FROM   dept
WHERE  EXISTS(SELECT *
              FROM   emp x
              WHERE  x.deptno = 20
                     AND EXISTS(SELECT *
                                FROM   emp y
                                WHERE  y.job = x.job
                                       AND y.deptno = dept.deptno))
       AND deptno <> 20;

SELECT deptno
FROM   dept
WHERE  EXISTS(SELECT *
              FROM   emp x
              WHERE  x.deptno = dept.deptno
                     AND EXISTS(SELECT *
                                FROM   emp y
                                WHERE  y.job = x.job
                                       AND y.deptno = 20))
       AND deptno <> 20;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they are equivalent. They are also equivalent to:

```
SELECT deptno
FROM   dept
WHERE  EXISTS ( SELECT *
                FROM   emp x
                  JOIN emp y
                    ON y.job=x.job
                WHERE  x.deptno = 20
                  AND  y.deptno = dept.deptno 
              ) 
  AND  deptno <> 20;
```

Answer (score 2):

The first query looks for department D with an employee Y in department 20 who has the same job as an employee X in department D.

The second query does the same but with X and Y switched.  So I think they are equivalent.

The query is perhaps simpler with `join` instead of `not exists` subqueries.  For example, this would be functionally equivalent:

```
select  distinct dept.deptno
from    dept
join    emp x
on      x.deptno = dept.deptno
join    emp y
on      y.deptno = 20
        and y.job = x.job
where   dept.deptno <> 20
```

Comment: `x` and `y` cannot be the same because `x.deptno=20` and `y.deptno<>20` or vice versa.

Comment: @ypercube: Good point!  looks like I misread the question.  I'll edit the answer.